# got this while trying to installing sodium

Tags: javascript, npm

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\hagde\Desktop\Coding\Discord_bot\node_modules\sodium
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js --preinstall
npm ERR! Please set your Microsoft Visual Studio version before you run npm install
npm ERR! Example for Visual Studio 2015:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     For you user only:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!         npm config set msvs_version 2015
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     Global:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!         npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Supported values are 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015
```

---

I tried "npm i sodium", "npm config set msvs_version 2015"

Comment: So you did `npm config set msvs_version 2015`  *before*  `npm i sodium`?